# GnuTLS not working in C, Eclipse on Windows

Tags: c, windows, eclipse-cdt

I want to use gnutls_global_init() in Eclipse (Windows).
I have GnuTLS installed in C:\GnuTLS
I know that i have to link GnuTLS somehow.

I navigate to Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Library Paths

1. If i put in "Library Paths" tab -> "C:\GnuTLS\win64-build\lib"
   i get error:

> /cygdrive/c/Users/HP/eclipse-workspace/domains/Debug/../src/domains.c:64:
> undefined reference to
> `gnutls_certificate_allocate_credentials' domains         C/C++ Problem

2. If i put in "Libraries" -> "C:\GnuTLS\win64-build\lib\libgnutls.dll.a"
   i get error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:
> cannot find -lC:\GnuTLS\win64-build\lib\libgnutls.dll.a: No such file
> or directory

I had the problem when fixing includes:
#include <gnutls/gnutls.h>
#include <gnutls/x509.h>
Finally fixed it just coppying those files to C:\cygwin64\usr\include

Maybe i could fix this by copying some dlls from GnuTLS to Cygwin, but where?

Comment: Did you try to specify only the library's name as "gnutls.dll"? The path is specified in "Library Paths", and the linker commonly adds "lib" as prefix and ".a" as suffix.

Comment: Yep, i tried C:\GnuTLS\win64-build\lib\libgnutls.dll, same - no such file.

Comment: No, just "gnutls.dll".

Comment: Problems remains, doesnt help :) switching to do C on Linux ;) too much problems

Comment: Good decision, Windows is not a good ground for programming. -- Another issue is the encoding of the path. Since you seem to use a Cygwin based compiler, you might need to specify the library path like "/cygdrive/c/GnuTLS/win64-build/lib".

Comment: I came back just to test it and it didnt help. I tried include just path or library itself, and the same. Actually in Linux i have already done everything with TLS :) I am happy that i switched